# Order data frame by column and display WITH indices

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have the following R data frame

```
> df
   a
1  3
3  2
4  1
5  3
6  6
7  7
8  2
10 8
```

I order it by the `a` column with the order function `df[ order(df),  ]`:

```
[1] 1 2 2 3 3 6 7 8
```

This is the result I want, BUT, how can list the whole data frame with the permuted indices?

The only thing that works is the following, but it seems sloppy and I don't really understand what it does:

```
> df[ order(df),  c(1,1) ] # I want this but without the a.1 column!!!!
   a a.1
4  1   1
3  2   2
8  2   2
1  3   3
5  3   3
6  6   6
7  7   7
10 8   8
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If we need the indices as well, use `sort` with `index.return = TRUE`

```
data.frame(sort(df$a, index.return=TRUE))
```